# Why does my array print hundreds of times during Project Euler?

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm finding the sum of all the multiples of 3 and 5 up to 1000 which prints correctly.  I am also trying to print the entire array.  My append and print array line are causing it to print 467 times for EACH appended item i.e. the first array printed is [3] then [3,5] then [3,5,6] until [3,5,6,...,1000].  How can I fix this so only [3,5,6,...,1000] is printed?

```
var startAtZero = 0
var numberArray = [Int]()

for number in 1...1000 {
    if number % 3 == 0 || number % 5 == 0 {
        startAtZero += number
        numberArray.append(contentsOf: [number])
        print(numberArray)
    }
}

print(startAtZero)
```

Comment: Unrelated but replace `numberArray.append(contentsOf: [number])` with `numberArray.append(number)`

Comment: If you want your `numberArray` to print just once at the end, why print it inside the loop?

Comment: @rmaddy Thank you.  It won't print outside because it is a for loop?

Comment: @Troy  it's a for loop but the var is declared out **numberArray** , you better read about variable scope

Comment: @Troy It's no different than your `startAtZero` variable and print statement.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
print(numberArray)
```

do

```
print(number)
```

//

According to your requirement it should be

```
for number in 1...1000 {
    if number % 3 == 0 || number % 5 == 0 {
        startAtZero += number
        numberArray.append(number)
         if i == 1000 {
             print(numberArray)
         }
    }
}

print(startAtZero)
```

//

Equivalent and has better performance

```
for number in 1...1000 {
    if number % 3 == 0 || number % 5 == 0 {
        startAtZero += number
        numberArray.append(number)
     }
}

print(numberArray)
print(startAtZero)
```

Comment: Incorrect, that just prints all of my numbers in 1...1000

Comment: @Troy No, that does not print all of the numbers, just the ones that are multiples of 3 and 5.

Comment: @Sh_Khan Yes I tried it and it prints out a list of all the numbers 1 to 1000 (that are the correct 467) not an array.  I put the print statement where print(numberarray) was.

Comment: This **[3,5,...1000]** will be available in the last for loop run , what will be the difference if you print it out  ???

Comment: @Sh_Khan Correct, regards!